# Showing a list of content that only authorised users can see

Tags: users, views

Most of the site is public however certain nodes need to be only visible to authorised users. I've got this up and running using Content Access but now I want to show a list of content that Anonymous users can't see.

I thought I'd be able to do it using Views and Contextual Filters but I can't seem to get just that content to show.

So, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use use Nodeqeue and views module to create a nodeqeue and assign permission using views module.

Comment: How can I use this to create a list though? I've never come across Nodequeue and it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for. The content is already being origanised by Control Access (for the rest of the site) to hide parts from non-authenticated users.

Answer (score 0):

If your page or block is created with Views, views will allow you to configure said page or block to be viewable only by people with certain permissions.  In D7, in the middle column, you have 'Page Settings > Access (about half way down)'; for blocks, same location. Click access and give this view to whatever role you want to be able to see it. If none of the existing roles suffice, just create a new one in 'People'

Hope that helps

Comment: I've used this technique to the View is only visible to certain roles - but I want to hide the content that is accessible to Anonymous users. I don't want to show my Authenticated users ALL the content - just the content that Anonymous users can't see.